# Is it possible to use multiple req() with OR condition?

Tags: r, shiny

I've learned that it's possible to use multiple AND `req()` such as `req(input$x, input$y)`. Is it possible to use `req()` with `input$x` OR `input$y`?

Comment: Are you looking for a syntax `isTruthy(input$x)|isTruthy(input$y)`

Comment: This works! I couldn't find how to use the `isTruthy` function anywhere yet. Can you make this an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this with

```
isTruthy(input$x)|isTruthy(input$y)
```

Or if there are many inputs

```
Reduce(`|`, lapply(c("x", "y"), \u isTruthy(input[[u]])))
```